# How to display text in label after clicking on button

Tags: c#, streamreader

How do I get display on my label after I click on my button.

For example, ( i keyed in A B C for my 3 textboxes, my .txt file will save A B C inside, my 3 labels will display A B C individually in each label once i click onto the readbutton. after that, i keyed in D E F for my 3 textboxes, the .txt file will have A B C D E F. after i click on my readbutton, I want the 3 labels to reflect D E F then followed by A B C then after i click again, it will shows D E F and vice versa. )

This is my program:

```
private void readButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    reader = new StreamReader("zzz.txt",true);
    while (reader.Peek() != -1)
    {
        label1.Text = reader.ReadLine();
        label2.Text = reader.ReadLine();
        label3.Text = reader.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code your using?

Comment: now i can only display 3 most recent text in my labels. i want to display the older text by clicking onto the readbutton.

Comment: So you want to add to the existing label text?

Comment: yes so the existing label will also display the older text when i click onto the readbutton. so everytime when i click the readbutton, it will display the old text that i keyed in before.

Comment: label1.Text+=reader.ReadLine(); just one inside the while loop will do. if you want to display all in one label.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding, my explanation is not so good. what i want is, for example ( i keyed in A B C for my 3 textboxes, my .txt file will save A B C inside, my 3 labels will display A B C individually in each label once i click onto the readbutton. after that, i keyed in D E F for my 3 textboxes, the .txt file will have A B C D E F. after i click on my readbutton, I want the 3 labels to reflect D E F then followed by A B C then after i click again, it will shows D E F and vice versa. )

Comment: @desync You may want to edit and clarify your question, your comment changes the question completely...

Answer (score 0):

For windows forms use the `.Text` property on the label(which even you are using):-

```
 private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int a = 420 / 10;
    lblResult.Text = a.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments it looks like you want this

```
label1.Text = label1.Text + reader.ReadLine();
label2.Text = label2.Text + reader.ReadLine();
label3.Text = label3.Text + reader.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the question has changed several times now, I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for.  However, if I understand what you are trying to do, I would suggest keeping the values in memory, and writing them to the file upon closing the application.

(Either that or look into FileStream, or something similar with seeking capabilities.)

Comment: @MMK sorry, misunderstood the question... I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

As I understand. Problem in ordering.

May be it would be better if you will use formatted file, like [cvs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) with additional column called "CreationDate", thereby you can sort your data by date and display it in appropriate order in labels.